# How can I move 5 GB data from one database to another faster?

Tags: mysql, database-recommendation, database-theory

I'm using MySQL as database with Windows server. I'm having 5 GB of data in database. Now I need to change my server and the question is that how can I transfer complete 5 GB data to one mysql database to another mysql database in **Fastest** way? What is the **Easiest** and **Fastest** method to do that? Any method / query / tool anyway?

Comment: **Faster** than what?  Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @JNK Sorry I corrected my question. It is **Fastest** and I couldn't find any way to do that directly

Comment: You have currently tagged both [tag:sql-server] and [tag:mysql]. When you say that you want to transfer "[from] one database to another database" do you mean "from MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server"? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @GordThompson Edit Done

Comment: Dhaval you might want to be specific even more. Like, do you have any down time window to perform this activity? Or you wanted to do without letting your customers to know about the migration. If yes let me know their sleeping hours :)

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to have a backup of your database anyway, so just do a full backup, copy it from the old server to the new one, and then restore it there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gord. Are you talking about simply import and export the database? if yes then there will be some limit of uploading and excecuting the query and if now then please let me know from where I can directly backup the database and restore it as I'm new to use server

Comment: Not export/import *per se*, but standard MySQL backup and restore processes, as outlined in the MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.1/en/backup-and-recovery.html).